# load activity with a different state than the default one

Tags: android

I have two activities in my application. Activity1 has a list view and two buttons(say button1 and button2). Based on which button user clicks the content in the listview changes accordingly. The default loading of activity is having button1 click contents loaded in activity1.
In my Activity2, I have a button(say button3) which when clicked, has to load activity1 but with the listview loaded with button2 click results, not with the default display which shows the button1 click results.
Any help on how can I acheive this? On the onclick event of button3 in activity2 I can load activity1 but that will load with the default state showing button1 click results.

Comment: thanks for your responses. Looks like handling it by passing data/flag using Intent will be the best way. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the state of your ListView by passing a extra string with IntentHandler when switching between the activities:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), yourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("LISTVIEW_STATE", myListViewState);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your recieving activities onCreate() method (in this case yourActivity) you can get the state with:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String recievedListViewState = intent.getStringExtra("LISTVIEW_STATE");
```

Comment: thanks for your responses. Looks like handling it by passing data/flag using Intent will be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

From second activity send Intent with a flag.
In first activity always lookout for this flag and trigger your second button code accordingly. For reference you can search for "passing data between activity" here or google.

Comment: thanks for your responses. Looks like handling it by passing data/flag using Intent will be the best way.

Comment: For detailed explanation refer MattDavis's answer. It does exactly want you want. Glad i could be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding Extras on your Intents.  Right now, when you start Activity1 from Activity2, you probably have code that looks something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can use the `putExtra()` method on the Intent that sets a key-value pair (called an extra) on this intent, making it look like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("LIST_TO_DISPLAY", "LIST_2");    
startActivity(intent);
```

The first argument to `putExtra()` (the key) is always a String, the second argument (the value) can be many different data types.  Here's it's also a String.

Once Activity1 starts, you can grab the Intent by using `getIntent()` then pull the extra from it, all in `onCreate()`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String whichList = intent.getStringExtra("LIST_TO_DISPLAY"); //which List now equals "LIST_2"

    if( whichList != null && "LIST_2".equals(whichList) )
    {
        //Set up List 2
    }
    else
    {
        //Set up the default list
    }
}
```

[Here's the docs for the Intent Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).  You can find explinations of all of the put and get Extra methods, as well as some other information that may be helpful when wanting to customize how you started Activities behave.

Comment: thanks for your responses. Looks like handling it by passing data/flag using Intent will be the best way. –

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand so there are several things which would you think.

...

Activity1 -> Button1 -> Listview (Content A)

Activity1 -> Button2 -> ListView (Content B)

Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Button3 -> Activity1 -> ListView (Content B)

So you could

in activity1

start startActivity(intentActivity2);

In activity2

intentResult.putExtra("cmd", "button3");
onbutton click setResult(RESULT_OK,intentresult)
and finish

back in Activity1

onActivityResult 
resultIntent.getExtra("cmd")